# SQL query to fetch a column where count is greater than 1 in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am facing an issue with where the table structure is as below

```
SHIPMENT_GID || COST_TYPE || COST
12233        ||B          ||1180
12234        ||B          ||1300
12235        ||B          ||1100
12236        ||B          ||1400
12233        ||B          ||200
12233        ||A          ||300
```

Here I want is the SQL query should fetch me unique shipment Id that has Count(cost_type  = B) >1

I had the following query but it is not working

```
select * from shipment_cost where shipment_gid = (select SHIPMENT_GID 
                                                  from shipment_cost 
                                                  where (count(COST_TYPE = 'B')>1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
 SELECT SHIPMENT_GI, count(*)
 FROM shipment_cost
 WHERE COST_TYPE='B' 
 GROUP BY SHIPMENT_GI
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: @mrugen `HAVING COUNT(SHIPMENT_GI) > 1` would be better when `SHIPMENT_GI` can be `NULL` as `COUNT(*)` also count `NULL` values where `COUNT(<column>)` does not , not sure that results you are after?

Comment: Thanks, Bruce it  worked

Comment: See @Raymond Nijland comment in cases of nulls.